# Is it possible to fetch data from a JavaScript based website?

Tags: javascript, web

For example, I want to fetch some of the product details from some website like http://www.peapod.com

I can get all the concise product information from search. For example, when searching "cheese," I can get all such products' weight and price. But if I want to get more detailed data, I need to click the link for each product, I can do this from web browser, but when I'm trying to do it from html file, the only link information I got is of the form "javascript: ntn (product_id, some_int)."

The real http link is of form http://www.peapod.com/itemDetailView.jhtml?productId=106871&NUM=1352479733231, where the first number is product id, the second number (I guess) is session id. I can find out the product id from link address in the parent page by its JavaScript call, but how can I get the session id?

When I try to download the search page, I got a bunch of js file, I guess those js files may help me get the session id. But I have no idea on how to call those js files.

please help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to write something to call the JavaScript functions, you should use a tool like Fiddler to see what happens when you click those links. Most likely, what those functions do is issue an HTTP request to retrieve the data to display. It would be much easier for your application to make  that same HTTP request and extract the data rather than use screen scraping techniques.